# Android AutoCompleteTextView's addTextChangedListener() method

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I've problem about `AutoCompleteTextView`'s `addTextChangedListener()` method.I've a button when click this button i must create dynamic `AutoCompleteTextViews`.I can do it which i use `addview()`method to add dynamic `AutoCompleteTextViews` but i can't call `addTextChangedListener()` method for every dynamic `AutoCompleteTextViews`.How can i solve this problem?

Comment: you dont need any `TextWatcher` for `AutoCompleteTextView` to work, just implement the `Filter` in the adapter

Comment: `"but i can't call addTextChangedListener() method for every dynamic AutoCompleteTextViews"` i dont see any reason why you are not able to do that, but as i said you dont need any `TextWatcher` at all

Comment: I solved my problem thanks